# How to mongo aggregate with lookup and geoIntersects

Tags: mongodb, coordinates, lookup, point

I want to lookup which users are in a specific area, so, if i have these objects on users collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6197a78308591026b742cbc7"),
    "longitude" : -8.88180350512795,
    "latitude" : 38.5628716186268
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6199798916317b0c2dcab874"),
    "longitude" : -9.15904389999993,
    "latitude" : 38.7235087
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6199798916317b0c2dcab874"),
    "longitude" : -8.6923178,
    "latitude" : 41.1846394
}
```

And i have other collection deliveryareas with this object:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("6197ebf6fdbd8f6b06c97c57"),
    "area" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            [ 
                [ 
                    -9.0556241, 
                    38.4989521
                ], 
                [ 
                    -9.0551516, 
                    38.4964531
                ], 
                [ 
                    -9.0522346, 
                    38.4950589
                ], 
                [ 
                    -9.0526648, 
                    38.4940872
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("6197ebf6fdbd8f6b06c97c58")
    }
}
```

Making this query:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'deliveryareas',
        let: { longitude: '$longitude', latitude: '$latitude' },
        pipeline: [
            { $match: {
                area: {
                    $geoIntersects: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type: 'Point',
                            coordinates: [ '$$longitude', '$$latitude' ],
                        },
                    },
                }
            } },
        ],
        as: 'inRegion',
    },
},
])
```

if i run the query directly in the deliveryareas collection it works, but over the pipeline on lookup don't work and it's giving the error "Point must only contain numeric elements", can anyone tell me why?

Comment: For debugging purposes - try removing the match stage, and just project the values and types of logitude and latitude, perhaps one of the documents has an array or other type that you're not expecting?

Comment: No, if in the pipeline just project the variables everything appears to be ok, showing the variables with the numbers.